# jcoverflip reinitialize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use [jcoverflip](https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip) to create a image carusel. I have to add the images dynamicly and need to reintialize the coveflip.

I tried the workaround from there [F.A.Q.](https://github.com/NewSignature/jcoverflip/wiki/Questions-and-Answers)

```
$('#flip').jcoverflip(); //Build it
$('#flip').jcoverflip('destroy'); //All the elements are there but jCoverflip is gone
//Add and remove elements
$('#flip').jcoverflip(); //Build again
```

but get the following error on destroying

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined` for `$.widget.prototype.destroy.apply( this, arguments );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modified Version of jcoverflip of [vlc](http://code.google.com/p/vlc-shares/source/browse/trunk/public/js/jquery.jcoverflip.js?r=213) works for me.